# System hangs while changing wallpaper

Tags: desktop, pantheon, release-odin, wallpaper, bugs

I've been using elementary os 6. Whenever I try to change the desktop wallpaper, the system hangs indefinitely.

Sometimes the wallpaper changes abruptly, other times it hangs for so long that I have to force restart the system.

Today I encountered the same issue while changing the wallpaper that I had to restart my system. After logging in, the system hung again. From now on the system hangs every time I log in. I'm also unable to access tty1. Hence I am forced to perform a clean install.

It would be realty helpful if anyone can suggest a fix for this issue.

Comment: Im having a similar sounding problem. did you get an answer?

Comment: I reported this same issue when eos6 was in beta. Looks like it is fixed now